# How to best retrieve specific sub-elements of a document with a regex (or similar in mongo)

Tags: mongodb-query

I have a document with the following structure, is it possible (e.g. using $regex) to return just the position elements which start "^raw_" (as there can be many variants of raw_ elements)?

I can easily return all "positions" elements with a simple projection but can't seem to figure out (looking at examples in the doc's) if/how I can pull out just those that start with raw_ (I have tried a few variations of $elemMatch but without much luck).

Is it possible somehow? Can someone provide an example if so?

`{
       "_id": '1',
      "positions": {
        "raw_1": {
           "123": 125.30,
           "456": 125.30,
           "789": 125.30,
        }, 
        "raw_2": {
           "123": 125.30,
           "456": 125.30,
           "789": 125.30,
        },
        "calc_1": {
           "123": 125.30,
           "456": 125.30,
           "789": 125.30,
        }, 
        "calc_2": {
           "123": 125.30,
           "456": 125.30,
           "789": 125.30,
        }
      }
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that it' possible to query against the document keys with $regex. If it's possible to adjust the document structure, I suggest the following:

```
{
    "_id": "1",
    "positions": {
        "raw": [
            {
                "entry": "1",
                "values": {
                    "123": 125.30,
                    "456": 125.30,
                    "789": 125.30,
                 }
            },
            {
                "entry": "2",
                "values": {
                    "123": 125.30,
                    "456": 125.30,
                    "789": 125.30,
                 }
            }
        ],
        "calc": [
            {
                "entry": "1",
                "values": {
                    "123": 125.30,
                    "456": 125.30,
                    "789": 125.30,
                 }
            },
            {
                "entry": "2",
                "values": {
                    "123": 125.30,
                    "456": 125.30,
                    "789": 125.30,
                 }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Given this structure, it is much easier to return only the raw entries you are interested in:

```
db.col1.find({ "_id" : "1" },{ "positions.raw" : true });
```